# Finding best item to maximize expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose in a store with $n$ products we want to advertise one of the products to a customer. we know that for this customer the probability of buying the `i`th product is $p_{i}$. When the customer steps in the store we can advertise one of the product. If the `j`th product is advertised then the probability of buying it becomes $p_{j}$. The customer cant buy more than one of each product. We want to maximize the expected value of number of products that are bought. Which product should we advertise?

This the full problem. I still don't get what the final result should look like but for solving the problem I think we should define a $X_{i}$ showing that if the product is sold or not. If yes then the random variable is 1 and if no then it is 0. I think that it has something to do with conditional expectation but I don't know where to go from here

Comment: Not a great notation.  You appear to use $p_k$ to denote the probability of buying item $k$ whether or not it is advertised.  You should also edit your post to indicate the dependence (or independence) of the various purchases.

Comment: Perhaps you could use $p_i (0)$ for the probability of item $i$ being bought if it's not advertised and $p_i(1)$ when it is. Does the customer always buy something or can she leave the store empty-handed?

Comment: As a suggestion, I'd work this out completely for two products.  See if you can formulate the strategy conveniently in terms of the (unadvertised) $p_1,p_2$.  More generally, well it's just a matter of optimizing the sum $\left(\sum p_i \right)- p_k+q_k$ where I am using $q_k$ to denote the post-advertising probabilities.    That makes the strategy fairly clear, no?

Comment: @lulu I know the notation is not grate but it is the original questions notation. sorry but didn't get the strategy

Comment: @lulu I mean I get the formula you mentioned, but where should I go after that?

Comment: If I have understood the rules then the expected value, given that you advertise product $k$, is given by my formula.  It follows that you want to maximize $(q_k-p_k)$.

Comment: But...even if the notation in the original problem is poor, that's no reason to stick with it.  Use mine or come up with your own.